# Why is this powershell code snippet not working?

Tags: powershell

This particular powershell code does not work for me, I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here (I am in the process of learning Powershell - I am quite new to it)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text = "Testing"
$main_form.Width = 500
$main_form.height = 300
$main_form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$main_form.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.MaximizeBox = $false
$main_form.MinimizeBox = $false

#
$SetCheckBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$SetCheckBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$SetCheckBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
$SetCheckBox.Text = "Set"
$main_form.Controls.Add($SetCheckBox)

if($SetCheckBox.Checked -eq $true){
    $SetButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $SetButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(280,200)
    $SetButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
    $SetButton.Text = "Nothing Selected"
    $SetButton.AutoSize = $true
    $main_form.Controls.Add($SetButton)
}else{

}

$RefreshButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$RefreshButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,285)
$RefreshButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$RefreshButton.Text = "Refresh"
$RefreshButton.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.Controls.Add($RefreshButton)

$RefreshButton.Add_Click({
    $main_form.Refresh()
})
#

$main_form.Topmost = $true
$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

I expect it to add a button to my form when "$SetCheckBox.Checked" equals to $true", but nothing happens. No error code or anything.
Maybe this isn't how Powershell works?

Comment: Please provide enough code for us to test this scenario. We currently don't know how you are calling the snippet or how you WinForms is built :)

Comment: Assuming your `if` condition is satisfied, you have to do a `$main_form.refresh()` for the form changes to be reflected on your screen.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent Added the full code now :) (The code between the #blocks are the part that doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have everything setup, just not in the right place. You need to include the if statement inside the button press for it to be actioned. I didn't need to put a `Refresh()` in but I only tested in the ISE. This is currently working for me:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text = "Testing"
$main_form.Width = 500
$main_form.height = 300
$main_form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$main_form.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.MaximizeBox = $false
$main_form.MinimizeBox = $false

$SetCheckBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$SetCheckBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$SetCheckBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
$SetCheckBox.Text = "Set"
$main_form.Controls.Add($SetCheckBox)

$RefreshButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$RefreshButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,285)
$RefreshButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$RefreshButton.Text = "Refresh"
$RefreshButton.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.Controls.Add($RefreshButton)

$RefreshButton.Add_Click({
    if($SetCheckBox.Checked -eq $true){
        Write-Host "testing"
        $SetButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $SetButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(280,200)
        $SetButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
        $SetButton.Text = "Nothing Selected"
        $SetButton.AutoSize = $true
        $main_form.Controls.Add($SetButton)
    }else{
        Write-Host "testing2"
    }
})

$main_form.Topmost = $true
$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Do not know why my comment got removed, but thank you @i-t-delinquent - that worked perfectly, I appreciate the help :)